# How to I disable ripple/wave effect when touch with stylus on windows 8?

Tags: wpf, windows, windows-8, touch

Does anyone know how to remove the wave/ripple effect when I touch with stylus on windows 8?

I'm asking this because the wave/ripple effect does not appears when I'm using InkCanvas on WPF. I know that it is possible, I just don't know how.

Comment: The request came from the client. :)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer:

```
Stylus.SetIsTapFeedbackEnabled(obj, false);
```